# why I get [1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3] instead of [1, 2, 3],[11, 2, 3]

Tags: python, list

```
sublista = [1, 2, 3]
lista = [sublista]
nsublista = sublista
nsublista[0] = sublista[0]+10
lista.append(nsublista)
print lista
```

Why do I get `[1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3]` instead of `[1, 2, 3],[11, 2, 3]`?

Comment: It prints `[[11, 2, 3], [11, 2, 3]]`

Answer (score 8):

Python doesn't copy implicitly.  When you do `nsublista = sublista`, `nsublista` and `sublista` are the same list object.  Changing an element in `nsublista` is reflected in `sublista`, because there's only one list.

`lista` contains the same list twice, so that's what prints.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]           # a = [1, 2, 3]
container = [a]         # a = [1, 2, 3]; container = [a]
b = a                   # b = a = [1, 2, 3]; container = [a]
b[0] = a[0]+10          # b = a = [11, 2, 3]; container = [a]
container.append(b)     # b = a = [11, 2, 3]; container = [a, a]
print lista
```

Comment: So @seppo - if you change the third line of your code to `nsublista = list(sublista)` then you will get what you were expecting

Comment: Or use `nsublista = sublista[:]`